# Override bundle config files

Tags: php, symfony

im trying to override a config files from a bundle. Im doing everthing like here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html, but for me that solution dosent work.

I have a class which has function getParent()

```
public function getParent()
{
    return 'ParentBundle';
}
```

And a config file in Resources/config/storage.xml.
Why this storage.xml from child bundle dosent work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, have you cleared your cache ?

If it still doesn't work, you should ensure the budnle you are trying to override uses the `@FooBundle/Resource/config/storage.xml` syntax.